# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in WorkersController#create ,Couldn't find Company with 'id'=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i want to create a worker with the company_id. Now i need to place the company_id into the view but i get this error(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Company with 'id'=):), can anyone help me to see where did i do wrong?Thanks

[worker controller(part 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axvMa.png)

[worker controller(part2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YIlL.png)

[views/new.html.erb(where the form is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmZtl.png)

[Error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLVcJ.png)

Comment: You don't say what "this error" is?

Comment: hi,this is the error come out  ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Company with 'id'=):

Comment: and this is the parameters                                                     Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "worker"=>{"name"=>"testuser"
, "email"=>"test@example.com", "phone_number"=>"1234567887", "address"=>"penang"
, "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "company_id"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create worker"}

Comment: company_id is nil. It breaks here `@company_id = Company.find(params[:worker][:company_id])`

Comment: yes, but i dunno how to fixed it because i'm very new in ruby, can you teach me how to correct it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add value to `..."company_id"=>"**ID_YOU_ARE_SEARCHING_FOR**"...`

It should be set on the call to your create method

Comment: thank you for your solution~~help me a lot

Answer (score 0):

In your Form views/new.html.erb, you're passing company_id as hidden_field but value has not been passed there, which is the reason for the error(company_id's value not present)

```
<%= f.hidden_field :company_id %>
```

Below line would fix it, you need to pass value in your form like shown below. This would pass 1 as company_id, but you need to change it based upon how and from where you're getting this value.

```
<%= f.hidden_field :company_id, value: 1 %>
```